# coinmarketcap new api Node.js to php

Tags: javascript, php, api

I'm taking data from coinmarketcap.com using their API. This week they updated the api so now you need an api key to access the data.
Now I need to add more details to the http call. In the API document they show this NodeJs code:

```
/* Example in Node.js ES6 using request-promise, concepts should translate to your language of choice */

const rp = require('request-promise');
const requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest',
  qs: {
    start: 1,
    limit: 5000,
    convert: 'USD'
  },
  headers: {
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'b54bcf4d-1bca-4e8e-9a24-22ff2c3d462c'
  },
  json: true,
  gzip: true
};

rp(requestOptions).then(response => {
  console.log('API call response:', response);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('API call error:', err.message);
});
```

Can anyone help me convert the attached nodejs code to php?

Comment: Did the code below work for you ?

Comment: no i need new php code i think best way for this is CURL

Comment: Ok, it will be better if you update your question to make it clear your looking for a specific PHP way of doing it rather than simply stating your after a node to php conversion which can be done in multiple ways.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, converting their nodeJs code to PHP might be an unproductive task if you have been using PHP all along to work with Coinmarketcap's API.

I assume you have been using cURL to access their API before the update happened and API_KEY became needed for requests.

Simply add the following to your cURL request in PHP and replace `API_SECRET` with the api key you received from [HERE](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY:API_SECRET'
));
```